# Remove spacing in a TD element that contains a list

Tags: html, css

I'd like to remove the padding present in the first row in the table, so it is the same height as the second row. I'm not sure where the padding is coming from, as I've set the padding to zero in the `td` `ul` and `li` elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/d9no97vL/

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><ul><li>abc</li><li>def</li></ul></td>
    <td>this row is too wide</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>this row is just right</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And the css:

```
ul li { display: inline; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
table { border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid black; }
td { padding: 0px; border: 1px solid black; }
```

Comment: Need to reset the `ul` padd http://jsfiddle.net/d9no97vL/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because of the default padding/margin on the `ul` element (dictated by the browser style sheets). Add the following:

```
ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d9no97vL/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue was with the ul li.

instead of using:

```
ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Use:

```
ul,li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d9no97vL/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Add This css style to your styles

```
ul {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/d9no97vL/7/